# TTL script to print numbers?

Tags: teraterm

How can we write a TTL script to print first 10 numbers? This is what I have tried:

```
for i 1 10
dispstr 'i'
next
```

but it is not printing numbers.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, an integer value passed to the [`dispstr`](http://www.teraterm.org/manual/en/macro/command/dispstr.html) command is expected to be an ASCII value. In other words, `dispstr 48` would display the character `0`, `dispstr 49` would display `1`, `dispstr 65` would display `A` and so on.

To display the integer values *as integers*, you can use the [`int2str`](http://www.teraterm.org/manual/en/macro/command/int2str.html) command to convert them to strings:

```
for i 1 10
  int2str s i
  dispstr s
next
```

You could also format the output using one of the [`sprintf`](http://www.teraterm.org/manual/en/macro/command/sprintf2.html)-type commands:

```
for i 1 10
  sprintf2 s '%d' i
  dispstr s
next
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested ok.
You can use as below:

```
for i 1 10
    sprintf2 s 'echo %d' i
    sendln s
next
```